# the dist folder is not being created

Tags: ecmascript-6

i'm trying to build gulp on ES6 modules, I got stuck at the very first stage: the function of copying files from the src folder to dist does not work and does not create the dist folder itself, despite the fact that the terminal outputs work without errors. after I prescribed the watcher function and the same behavior, the file is created and tracking and copying is not performed, please help, I will be very grateful)

-gulpfile.js

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import { path } from "./gulp/config/path.js";

global.app = {
path: path,
gulp: gulp
}

import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";

function watcher() {
gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy)
}

const dev = gulp.series(copy, watcher);

gulp.task('default', dev);
```

-path.js

```
import * as nodePath from 'path';
const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve());

const buildFolder = './dist';
const srcFolder = './src';

export const path = {
build: {
    files: '${buildFolder}/files/',
},
src: {
    files: '${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*',
},
watch: {
    files: '${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*',
},
clean: buildFolder,
buildFolder: buildFolder,
srcFolder: srcFolder,
rootFolder: rootFolder,
ftp: ''
}
```

-copy.js

```
export const copy = () => {
return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.files)
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.files))
}
```

Comment: `"${buildFolder}/files/"` does not work. You mean to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as shared here shows that you're not using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) properly so that gulp is trying create a folder called `${buildFolder}` which is not a valid name for a folder.

This should make it work:

path.js

```js
import * as nodePath from "path";
const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve());

const buildFolder = "./dist";
const srcFolder = "./src";

export const path = {
  build: {
    files: `${buildFolder}/files/`,
//         ^ Note the back ticks here instead of the quotation mark
  },
  src: {
    files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`,
//         ^ Note the back ticks here instead of the quotation mark
  },
  watch: {
    files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`,
//         ^ Note the back ticks here instead of the quotation mark
  },
  clean: buildFolder,
  buildFolder: buildFolder,
  srcFolder: srcFolder,
  rootFolder: rootFolder,
  ftp: "",
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend, everything worked)